# Constant Timer doesn't work with jmeter in command line

Tags: xml, jmeter, jmx

I have a jmeter test in which there is constants timers attached with websocket request, but when I launch the test with jmeter, using command line, jmeter doesn't take care of timers

```
<eu.luminis.jmeter.wssampler.SingleWriteWebSocketSampler enabled="true" guiclass="eu.luminis.jmeter.wssampler.SingleWriteWebSocketSamplerGui" testclass="eu.luminis.jmeter.wssampler.SingleWriteWebSocketSampler" testname="WebSocket Single Write Sampler">
              <boolProp name="TLS">false</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="server" />
              <stringProp name="port">80</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="path" />
              <boolProp name="binaryPayload">true</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="requestData">00 00 00 00 20 18 00 01 00 ff 00 ff 00 ff 10 08 00 00 00 00</stringProp>
              <boolProp name="createNewConnection">false</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="optional">false</boolProp>
            </eu.luminis.jmeter.wssampler.SingleWriteWebSocketSampler>
            <hashTree>
        <ConstantTimer enabled="true" guiclass="ConstantTimerGui" testclass="ConstantTimer" testname="Constant Timer">
                <stringProp name="ConstantTimer.delay">60000.0</stringProp>
              </ConstantTimer>
              <hashTree />
              <ConstantTimer enabled="true" guiclass="ConstantTimerGui" testclass="ConstantTimer" testname="Constant Timer">
                <stringProp name="ConstantTimer.delay">60008.427676</stringProp>
              </ConstantTimer>
              <hashTree />
            </hashTree>
```

But when I put the constant timer above the websocket sampler (which will impact every websocket sampler, not just this one), jmeter takes care of the timer

My result looks like this

```
summary +      1 in 00:00:31 =    0.0/s Avg:  3259 Min:  3259 Max:  3259 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary +  11445 in 00:00:07 = 1618.1/s Avg:     0 Min:     0 Max:   567 Err: 10953 (95.70%) Active: 0 Started: 1 Finished: 1
summary =  11446 in 00:00:38 =  304.2/s Avg:     0 Min:     0 Max:  3259 Err: 10953 (95.69%)
```

But I have several timers, and one is 60 seconds (like the one above)

Answer (score 0):

JMeter timers obey [JMeter scoping rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) so if you want the Constant Timer to be applied to one specific sampler only - you need to make it a **child** of the sampler

[image]

Also looking into [Constant Timer source](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/src/components/org/apache/jmeter/timers/ConstantTimer.java#L109) it seems that you need to provide a [Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) value so change these `60000.0` and `60008.427676` to `60000` and `60008` correspondingly.

Example test plan which creates 1 request per 60 seconds:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.1.1 r1855137">
    <hashTree>
        <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
            <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
            <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
                <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
        </TestPlan>
        <hashTree>
            <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
                <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
                    <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
                    <intProp name="LoopController.loops">-1</intProp>
                </elementProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
                <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
            </ThreadGroup>
            <hashTree>
                <eu.luminis.jmeter.wssampler.SingleWriteWebSocketSampler guiclass="eu.luminis.jmeter.wssampler.SingleWriteWebSocketSamplerGui" testclass="eu.luminis.jmeter.wssampler.SingleWriteWebSocketSampler" testname="WebSocket Single Write Sampler" enabled="true">
                    <boolProp name="TLS">false</boolProp>
                    <stringProp name="server">echo.websocket.org</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="port">80</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="path"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="connectTimeout">20000</stringProp>
                    <boolProp name="binaryPayload">false</boolProp>
                    <stringProp name="requestData">foo</stringProp>
                    <boolProp name="createNewConnection">true</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="loadDataFromFile">false</boolProp>
                    <stringProp name="dataFile"></stringProp>
                </eu.luminis.jmeter.wssampler.SingleWriteWebSocketSampler>
                <hashTree>
                    <ConstantTimer guiclass="ConstantTimerGui" testclass="ConstantTimer" testname="Constant Timer" enabled="true">
                        <stringProp name="ConstantTimer.delay">60000</stringProp>
                    </ConstantTimer>
                    <hashTree/>
                </hashTree>
            </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

You can also consider using [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler to introduce pauses as the alternative to the Constant Timer